# Why does my DBI program complain about 'Undefined subroutine &DBD::Pg::db::_login'?

Tags: perl, authentication, dbd

I am trying to use PostgreSQL database for storing Apache's session information, but I can't get it to work. It is failing with the following error:

```
 Undefined subroutine &DBD::Pg::db::_login
```

It seems that MySQL users have run into the same problem in DBD::MySQL::db. I have the latest CPAN version of both DBI and DBD::Pg. It doesn't seem that the `_login` function is there in the module. Any ideas how to get around this problem? I appreciate your help!

Thanks

Comment: You need to post more details, including code.  A stack trace (with the help of Carp::Always) would also be good.

Answer (score 2):

Browsing back through the history, there has never been a Perl method named `_login` defined in the package `DBD::Pg::db` (which is defined in Pg.pm), and the invocation is explicitly `DBD::Pg::db::_login()`.

This is a guess, but I think that `_login` is a C function that's bound through XS, and that's why you can't find its source in the module.  That would indicate some problem with the Postgres library that it's trying to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for point me in the right direction! The libpg.so (Postgres) library not getting loaded properly was in fact the problem. I didn't know what a missing function like that meant.